# pandas appending a streaming data series

Tags: pandas

I am trying to append a streaming data series to a pandas dataframe.
The columns are constant. I have used the following

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import time
while True:
    ltp=random.randint(0, 100)
    trade={'token':12345,'name':'abc','ltp':ltp}
    time.sleep(2)
    df=pd.DataFrame(trade,index=[1])
    df=df.append(trade,ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
```

In the above, only the ltp values keep changing.

The output i get is  only two rows with same LTP and not an expanding serialised dataframe with new data.

The output is:

```
  token name  ltp

0  12345  abc    9
1  12345  abc    9
   token name  ltp
0  12345  abc   93
1  12345  abc   93
   token name  ltp
0  12345  abc   92
1  12345  abc   92
   token name  ltp
0  12345  abc   10
1  12345  abc   10
```

Further, am not sure  why the same LTP is appearing twice for index 0 & 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you create `DataFrame` object each iteration, using this line:

```
while True:
    ...
    df=pd.DataFrame(trade,index=[1])
    ...
```

You need to create new `DataFarme` before starting the `while` loop, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import time
# init new DataFrame with headers as columns
headers = ['token' ,'name' ,'ltp']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)
while True:    
    ltp = random.randint(0, 100)
    trade = {'token':12345,'name':'abc','ltp':ltp}
    time.sleep(2)  
    df = df.append(trade, ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
```